# Best way to add objects' field to a list

Tags: java, list, object

So I have this GameType class:

```
public class GameType {
    private final String name;

    public GameType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and I have a list of my game types, so, basically I want to print all of my GameType classes' `name` field and I am using Java 8, this is what I have done so far:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
gameTypes.forEach(gameType -> list.add(gameType.getName()));
System.out.println(list);
```

So, what I am asking is, **is there a better way to do that?**

Comment: `System.out.println(gameTypes.stream().map(GameType::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()));` --- Or use `.collect(Collectors.joining(", "))` if you don't want the output to have the `[ ]` around it.

Comment: `gameTypes.forEach(gameType -> System.out.println((gameType.getName()));` print every data in newline

Comment: Thank you @Andreas, that is what exactly I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
System.out.println(gameTypes.stream()
                             .map(GameType::getName)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```